# nginx website behind a router connects ok with myserver.local but asks for username and password when accessed via myserver.mydomain.com

Tags: nginx, node.js

nginx website behind a router connects ok with myserver.local but asks for username and password when accessed via my myserver.mydomain.com

All I wanted is to expose one of my Node.js test sites to some outside users and it asks for username and password. How can I do this?

My configuration consists of an apt-get(ed) nginx and my website .conf file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/website.conf

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     myserver.local;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/myserver.local.access.log combined;
        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Comment: What does "behind a router" mean?

Comment: Lan ip is 192.168.0.10 and the router 192.168.0.1 and I forward the 80 port on 192.168.0.10 to port 80 on 192.168.0.1 manually form the router.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a professional setup. Is this some kind of home router? What router? Have you considered the possibility that the router is doing this instead of forwarding the traffic?

Comment: It's a Linksys, I do this routinely for VNC or SSH, my external ip never changes so I can ssh directly to a machine on my lan through the router.

Comment: @MichaelHampton any thoughts on this, the 401 Unauthorized is certainly Nginx having some kind of security all around. Maybe it's figuring out URL is myserver.mydomain.com instead of myserver.local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this one. Had to add the **myserver.mydomain.com** next to the local one and **default**.

```
server {
        listen          80 default;
        server_name     myserver.local myserver.mydomain.com;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/myserver.local.access.log combined;
        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```